# Neural Network Architecture for unordered data

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, recurrent-neural-network

Lets say you have 10 features of 500 categories. A category can only occur once per input. The features can be in any particular order. eg [1,2,3,4,5,...], [5,3,4,2,1,...], etc.. And the order does not matter so [1,2,3,4,5,...] = [5,3,4,2,1,...]. So you shuffle your training data to train the network on the unordered data.

Now you want to feed this to your neural network. 3 architectures come to my mind:

1. MLP (Input: embedding_dim x n_features)
2. LSTM with embedding (Input: embedding_dim, Sequence Len: n_features)
3. LSTM with one hot encoding (Input: feature_dim, Sequence Len: n_features)

Which of these perform better on unordered data form your evidence based research?

Do you have any other architectures on your mind that perform well on unordered data. (maybe where shuffling the training data is not even necessary)

Comment: It also lacks details, is opinion-based, and asks for recommendations, all of which are [reasons for closure](https://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions).

Comment: i do not see how this is opinion based. maybe some nn model has an edge on learning form high dimensional unordered data like conv nets perform well on images. probably you can even measure it....

Answer (score 1):

What are you actually trying to model? This information may give some clues on how to approach the problem.

If I am understanding correctly, you are trying to learn from unordered multisets of size 10. Each element may assume one of 500 categories.

It may help to do some preprocessing of your data. Two approaches that come to my mind are:

1. Each sample could be encoded as vector of size 500, where each component represents the multiplicity of the respective element, e.g. [1,1,1,1,3,3,3,4,4,5] would be represented as [4,0,3,2,1,0,...].
2. Another simple approach could be to reorder your samples. Otherwise, the number of different inputs would be extremely high, i.e. 500^10.

Comment: sorry for not being specific enough. the features are just binary.
the embedding should compensate for the high feature dimension. in case of an lstm the embedding might not even be needed.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't understand what you intend to do. I think you need to provide more context.